# What is an algebraic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I know that this question is at least "ridiculous" if you have internet access, though maybe this is the problem as it seems (many times, at least in my head). I found many books (or notes), like Miranda's *Riemann Surface and Algebraic Curves*, Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, Fulton's *Algebraic Curves* and so on, each one with a different definition.

Apparently, depends on the context that you're investigating them, however, because I'm not an expert and have no clue what's the right definition, or the most general one, can you give me please the most general one that comprises all the others (I'm saying that because the dimension plays important role here, for instance in dimension one over $\mathbb{C}$ we have another definition sometimes, as it admits a "Riemann surface" structure and a couple of notes define them alternatively as in this way).

Comment: see here for an answer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve

Comment: Thano you for your answer Graubner, though, as you do (I guess :)) wikipedia was the first thing I've checked. Because it is very vague in my head, can you please give me a better guidance?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris I'm confused by your question, since what happens usually is that what the author means by an algebraic curve depends heavily on context. Armando j18eos is right that the most general thing that someone *might* call an algebraic curve is a scheme of Krull dimension one, but your references would probably define an algebraic curve as a "proper integral scheme of Krull dimension one over an algebraically closed field $k$," and Miranda in particular would probably demand that $k = \mathbf{C}$.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama thank you for your comment! I'm confused though by it. If you read the comment below his answer I think that you will understand why he edited the answer. I've written that I do understand the relation between the context and the definition, I'm just seeking for the general definition. And in Hartshorne's book seems that is exactly the one you mentioned. Armando's answer justifies more or less what you written. That's the story!

Comment: @TakumiMurayama Also you are right!, for example: a compact Riemann surface can be view as an integral, proper, separated scheme of finite type over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}$ of (Krull) dimension $1$. But because mayer_vietoris cites Miranda, Hartshorne and Fulton's books: I supposed that he looked for a general definition of algebraic curve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Classical approach.**

For simplicity, let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field: an algebraic curve $X$ in $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}}$ (the *affine $n$-dimensional space over $\mathbb{K}$*) is an algebraic set $X$ (the zero locus of a finite family of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{K}$) which *(Krull) dimension is purely $1$*;

what do I mean for "$X$ has pure (Krull) dimension $1$"? I mean that the unique closed, irreducible, proper and non-empty subsets of the *irreducible components* of $X$ are the *points of $X$*; equivalently the coordinates ring $\mathbb{K}[X]$ has Krull dimension $1$.

**Scheme approach.**

Let $X$ be a scheme: it is an algebraic curve if it has pure (Krull) dimension $1$;

for exact, this is equivalent to the existence of an affine open covering $\{\operatorname{Spec}R_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $X$ such that any $\operatorname{Spec}R_i$ has (Krull) dimension $1$; that is the (Krull) dimension of any $R_i$ is $1$. (See Vakil FOAG, December 29 2015 version, definition 11.1.3 and exercise 11.1.B.)

Comment: Do you know anything about the scheme-theoritic approach? How does this goes through the above definition that you gave me?

Comment: Ah!, I did not undestand your necessity of scheme-theoretic approach: no problem; I modify my answer. ;)

Comment: just out of curiosity, why the downvote here?

Comment: By the way, thanks for editing your answer!

Comment: I don't know: I can't vote my answers\questions; if my answer is useful: can you upvote it?

Comment: I did it! And it is useful, was just curious because seems to be correct indeed! Anyway, thank you again.

Comment: As FOAG is updated quite frequently, perhaps it is appropriate to also include which version of FOAG you are referencing?

Comment: Ok: I had add the date version. :) ;)

Answer (score 2):

An algebraic plane curve over an algebraically closed field $k$ is by definition the zero set of a polynomial equation in one variable. For example 
$y= x^3-ax+b$ is such an example for $x\in k$. This is not a very rigorous definition but it shoulds give an idea of what an algebraic curve is. Note that many people use the words algebraic curves and Riemann surface interchangeably which is slightly incorrect. A Riemann surface (and here we are interested about compact ones) carries less information than a smooth algebraic curve since the later has additional structure about its embedding (e.g. a compact Riemann surface together with a line bundle).